# ThreeJS / GLTFLoader responded with 404 about my gltf object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, three.js, gltf

I started an ASPNET MVC project and I tried to load a gltf object

GLTFLoader.js -> https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js

But my object isn't found... chrome console :

[image]

Project files:

[image]

I added something in web config:

[image]

```
<script src="~/Scripts/three.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            test: 'xd'
        }
    });
</script>
<script>
    var scene, renderer, camera;
    var cube;
    var controls;

    function initialize() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

        camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
        camera.position.set(800, 100, 1000);


        ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 100);
        scene.add(ambientLight)

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        $('#object').append(renderer.domElement);

        let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('Cars/tutorial/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
            car = gltf.scene.children[0];
            car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
            scene.add(gltf.scene);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        })
    }

    initialize();
</script>
```

Thanks!